# non-declaration statement outside function body

Tags: go, struct, slice

I wrote some code for API with Go regarding "Go Web Development Cookbook.pdf". I have face a error when I run the code. I declared a struck and initial with slice and within the slice I made two item of slice but I when going to this it shows "non-declaration statement outside function body" I searched over the internet for the solution.
Here is my code:

```
package main
import
(
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)
const
(
    CONN_HOST = "localhost"
    CONN_PORT = "8080"
)
type Route struct
{
    Name string
    Method string
    Pattern string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}
type Routes [] Route
var routes = Routes
{
    Route
    {
        "getEmployees",
        "GET",
        "/employees",
        getEmployees,
    },
    Route
    {
        "getEmployee",
        "GET",
        "/employee/{id}",
        getEmployee,
    },
}

type Employee struct
{
    Id string `json:"id"`
    FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
    LastName string `json:"lastName"`
}
type Employees []Employee
var employees []Employee
func init() {
    employees = employees {
        Employee{Id: "1", FirstName: "Foo", LastName: "Bar"},
        Employee{Id: "2", FirstName: "Baz", LastName: "Qux"},
    }
}

func getEmployees(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(employees)
}

func getEmployee(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    id := vars["id"]
    for _, employee := range employees {
        if employee.Id == id {
            if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(employee); err != nil {
                log.Print("error getting requested employee :: ", err)
            }
        }
    }
}
func AddRoutes(router *mux.Router) *mux.Router {
    for _, route := range routes {
        router.
        Methods(route.Method).
        Path(route.Pattern).
        Name(route.Name).
        Handler(route.HandlerFunc)
    }
    return router
}
func main() {
    muxRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    router := AddRoutes(muxRouter)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(CONN_HOST+":"+CONN_PORT, router)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error starting http server :: ", err)
        return
    }
}
```

"var routes = Routes" line indicate the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code formatting have problem, in `Go` you need to maintain the convention for putting curly braces, you cannot put it in another line,  you need to do it like this way :

```
var routes = Routes{
    Route{
        "getEmployees",
        "GET",
        "/employees",
        getEmployees,
    },
    Route{
        "getEmployee",
        "GET",
        "/employee/{id}",
        getEmployee,
    },
}
```